# Php Object to JSON returns weird Json

Tags: php, json, cookies, type-conversion

I am working on a system where I retrieve user preferences and insert them into cookies with JSON because I have a Javascript file that needs to use the value in the cookie too.

Now, when i use JSON.Stringify() with javascript i get the data just as i expect it.
[image]

However, when i go to check the cookie after it has run the PHP script i get this:
[image]

Here is my code from the php file:

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event){
    if($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')){
        $selectedCategories = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser()->getProfile()->getCategories();
        setcookie("userInterests",json_encode(get_object_vars($selectedCategories)),(time()+3*60*60*24*30));
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: thanks Thamilan, I wasn't allowed to post pictures.

Comment: Have you tried printing `json_encode(get_object_vars($selectedCategories))` to screen to see its valid json?

Comment: I know it may be a stupid question but I am not that at home in web development, could you explain where I can find the results from my print? I am using chrome

Comment: replace your setcookie line with print and then perhaps call `exit();` after to stop the rest of the script from executing, you should see the output on the page

Comment: Ultimately, i didn't manage to return the data, because after this line it immediately redirected the page. i found out that the format of the cookie was url-encoded. this can only be circumvented via raw cookies, but those can't hold arrays. so, i just went with this so i make sure to url decode it at the other end. i was told this works just fine for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had multiple problems: firstly I tried to enter an object(that I thought was an array) into the cookie. This had the weird cookie as a result, because the PHP cookie only held the start string for the urlencode.

Secondly, I didn't know that cookies automatically get urlencoded in PHP so that threw me of.
If I just use urldecode now, at the point where I am returning the data from the cookie. It should just pass the javascript cookie without editing it and my php cookie will be useable.